# How to Execute code after function is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, async-await

I have a code where basically I've created a function in which, by the help of jQuery ajax, I fetch a value and set it as a data attribute of an element.

then after calling the function, I store the data value in a variable.

But the problem is that I don't want to execute any code before the ajax function completes.

**JS**

```
function load_data(){
    $.ajax({
       .....,
       success: function (response) {
           $('.element').attr('data-foo', 'bar')
       }
    })
}
```

```
load_data(); //let the function set data first
console.log($('.element').data('foo')) //then execute this line
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Put that line of code in the "success" callback. That's what the callback is for

Comment: @Pointy yes I also thought about that but i was looking for other alternatives. Maybe by using async-await

Answer (score 2):

You can receive a callback function in `load_data` and execute it in the `success` function. Something like this:

```
function load_data(callback){
    $.ajax({
       .....,
       success: function (response) {
           $('.element').attr('data-foo', 'bar');
           callback();
       }
    })
}

load_data(function() {
  console.log($('.element').data('foo'));
});
```

Of course, if this is your real scenario, you could simply put `console.log($('.element').data('foo'));` directly inside the `success` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use, **Async-Await**. https://javascript.info/async-await

```
async function load_data(){
    await $.ajax({
       .....,
       success: function (response) {
           $('.element').attr('data-foo', 'bar')
       }
    });
    console.log($('.element').data('foo')) //then execute this line
}
load_data(); //let the function set data first
```

Also, you can do it using callback as well.

```
function load_data(callback){
    $.ajax({
       .....,
       success: function (response) {
           $('.element').attr('data-foo', 'bar');
           callback();
       }
    })
}

function doItLater(){
    console.log($('.element').data('foo')) //then execute this line
}

load_data(doItLater); //let the function set data first
```

You can pass the data as a parameter to doItLater for getting data to your current scope.

Comment: `$.ajax` does not return a promise afaik, therefore await would throw an error.

Comment: @Jaxi yes, it does return a Promise

Comment: @Pointy Ah, fair enough!

Answer (score 0):

try using .done()

```
load_data()
   .done(function(dataResponse){
           console.log($('.element').data('foo')) //then execute this line
   }); //let the function set data first
```

the code inside will run after a your ajax call is responded and `dataResponse` has any response from you ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is asynchronous. So, you have to listen for success event and do your stuff. You might achieve something similar to your needs by using await/async

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

```
const load_data = async () => {
    return await fetch('https://exmaple.com');
}

load_data();

$('.element').attr('data-foo', 'bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly possible due to Asynchronous ajax call.

There are two ways to achieve what you want

**1.**

- Create a function/s for the code you want to execute after successful ajax request
- Call that function/s from ajax success block

Eg.

```
function load_data(){
    $.ajax({
       .....,
       success: function (response) {
           $('.element').attr('data-foo', 'bar');
           console.log($('.element').data('foo')); // Your code goes here
       }
    })
}
```

**2**

- Return `$.ajax` in `load_data` function
- And use `.then` or `.done` function for load_data itself

Eg.

```
function load_data(){
    return $.ajax({
       .....,
           success: function (response) {
               $('.element').attr('data-foo', 'bar')
           }
        })
}

load_data().done(function() {
  console.log($('.element').data('foo')); // Your code goes here
});
```

*However, .done and .then do not behave the same. In particular, if a standard promise callback returns another promise, this will delay the resolution of all later promises. jQuery's then behaves like this, but done does not. It is not possible for a done callback to delay the resolution of later callbacks.*

Answer (score 0):

You could just put the console log inside of the success callback, after you set the element attribute.

If you don't want the console log written inside load_data (maybe you want to make load_data reusable, without the console log), you could put the console log in a callback function and pass the callback to load_data and call it in the ajax success function:

```js
function load_data(cb){
    $.ajax({
       .....,
       success: function (response) {
           $('.element').attr('data-foo', 'bar')
           cb();
       }
    })
}

function callback() {
  console.log($('.element').data('foo'))
}

load_data(callback);
```

Another option is to set `async: false` in the ajax settings object, which would prevent following code from being executed before the ajax function resolves, but this is not generally a recommended practice.

Answer (score 0):

with this:

```
$.when(load_data()).then(console.log($('.element').data('foo')));
```